# popupWindow.setOnDismissListener triggers popupmenu again

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu, android-popupwindow

Below is my code,
menu - ImageView
menubottom - ImageView
My requirement is to display the menubottom image when the popup is shown.

```
menu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {   
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {View layout=(View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.navigationbar, null);
        popupWindow = new PopupWindow(getApplicationContext());
        popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
        popupWindow.setContentView(layout);
        popupWindow.setHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        popupWindow.setWidth(swidth);
        popupWindow.setFocusable(false);
        popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        popupWindow.setAnimationStyle(-1);

            if(x==1)
            {   popupWindow.showAsDropDown(menubottom);
                menubottom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                x=0;                    
            }
            else
            {   
                popupWindow.dismiss();
                popupWindow=null;           
            }
            popupWindow.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDismiss() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    menubottom.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);   
                    x=1;

                }
            });

        }

}
```

ISSUE:
When the menu button is clicked popup shows and menubottom shown.
On pressing menu again, the popupmenu is hidden and then shown again.

On pressing outside the popupmenu, its working as expected(popup and menubottom is hidden)

I think, setOnDismissListener triggers the menu.setOnClickListener again.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So in short you want to display the PopMenu only once. After that,  you want to hide the button so that it cannot be displayed again... Right?

Answer (score 2):

i think the problem is after pop up, because menu button is outside `popupwindow`, `popupwindow` get dismissed and menu button's `onclick` trigger again.
so may be you can do something like this (initially `x=1`)

```
menu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{   
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {View layout=(View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.navigationbar, null);
    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(getApplicationContext());
    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    popupWindow.setContentView(layout);
    popupWindow.setHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popupWindow.setWidth(swidth);
    popupWindow.setFocusable(false);
    popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    popupWindow.setAnimationStyle(-1);

      /*  if(x==1)
        {   popupWindow.showAsDropDown(menubottom);
            menubottom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            x=0;                    
        }
        else
        {   
            popupWindow.dismiss();
            popupWindow=null;           
        } */

        if(x==0) {
            x=1;
        } else {
        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(menubottom);
            menubottom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
        popupWindow.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDismiss() {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                menubottom.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);   
                x=0;

            }
        });

    }
```

}

Comment: same issue still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I Believe you want to hide the menu button once the PopUp Menu is displayed..

In that case, Your Logic is quite incorrect... Try it this way...

```
boolean isDisplayed=false;


 menu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {   
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {View layout=(View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.navigationbar, null);
            popupWindow = new PopupWindow(getApplicationContext());
            popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
            popupWindow.setContentView(layout);
            popupWindow.setHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            popupWindow.setWidth(swidth);
            popupWindow.setFocusable(false);
            popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
            popupWindow.setAnimationStyle(-1);

                if(isDisplayed==false)
                {   popupWindow.showAsDropDown(menubottom);
                    menubottom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    isDisplayed=true;                    
                }
                else
                {   
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                    popupWindow=null; 
                    menubottom.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);          
                }


            }

    }
```

Comment: In this code, when  the popup is hidden by touching outside the popup box, the value of isDisplayed will be true, and on next press on menu button it will not display the popup. only on the second attempt it will show

Comment: Now it triggers on second click

Answer (score 0):

```
 PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(OrderSceenWithOrder.this,fabMain);
                popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.pop_up, popupMenu.getMenu());
                popupMenu.setOnDismissListener(new PopupMenu.OnDismissListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(PopupMenu popupMenu) {
                        fabMain.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(OrderSceenWithOrder.this, R.drawable.ic_baseline_add_24));
                    }

                });
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        Toast.makeText(OrderSceenWithOrder.this, ""+item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        fabMain.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(OrderSceenWithOrder.this, R.drawable.ic_baseline_add_24));
                        isClicked=true;
                        return true;
                    }

                });
                popupMenu.show();
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.